# How to generalize a formula?

Tags: function-construction, syntax

This is a piece of my code:

```
der[g_, x_, n_] := Sum[g[k, g[0, x]] BellY[n, k, 
         Table[g[i, x], {i, n - k + 1}]], {k, 0, n}]
g[0, x] := x
g[1, x] := x
g[2, x_] := Evaluate[der[g, x, 2 - 1]]
g[3, x_] := Evaluate[der[g, x, 3 - 1]]
num := 4
Expand[der[g, x, num]]
```

It works up to `n=4`. I want to make it work for higher `n`.

But trying to define

```
    g[n_, x_] := Evaluate[der[g, x, n - 1]]
```

returns error. What should I do?

Comment: are you looking for a closed form solution for `der` that works for all `n`?

Comment: @rm -rf I wonder why I have to write g[3, x_] := Evaluate[der[g, x, 3 - 1]] for 3 for 4, for 5 and cannot make a general definition.

Comment: It's because `Table` needs a numeric value for the iterator. Try replacing it with `Sum` and see if it simplifies things (no guarantees)

Comment: @rm -rf it does not work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any intuition whatsoever as to what your expected output is. The error message that emerges can be dealt with if you increase your iteration and recursion limits but seeing as I don't really know exactly how `BellY` works I leave this to you. If you write your `g` function recursively, like so

```
der[g_, x_, n_] := 
 Sum[g[k, g[0, x]] BellY[n, k, Table[g[i, x], {i, n - k + 1}]], {k, 0,
n}]
g[1, x] = x;
g[n_, x_] := g[n, x] = der[g, x, n - 1]
```

and evaluate:

```
Expand[der[g, x, 4]]
```

you get

```
x^5 + 11 x^6 + 11 x^7 + 8 x^8 + 4 x^9 + x^10 + x^11
```

And something more complicated, like evaluating:

```
Expand[der[g, x, 13]]
```

outputs (after some warnings re low recursion limits):

```
x^14 + 8178 x^15 + 1479726 x^16 + 45923846 x^17 + 459029454 x^18 + 
2208858006 x^19 + 7075642044 x^20 + 16806933760 x^21 + 
31816904623 x^22 + 51866622093 x^23 + 74193541415 x^24 + 
98180859588 x^25 + 119082181277 x^26 + 137536650290 x^27 + 
150143774552 x^28 + 157992149040 x^29 + 160050416326 x^30 + 
157096816119 x^31 + 150189370525 x^32 + 139814563126 x^33 + 
127454419592 x^34 + 113603426826 x^35 + 99578396788 x^36 + 
85494865250 x^37 + 72430802460 x^38 + 60247338445 x^39 + 
49525049687 x^40 + 40031803598 x^41 + 32046236578 x^42 + 
25240371714 x^43 + 19719393876 x^44 + 15171635174 x^45 + 
11589845200 x^46 + 8724377910 x^47 + 6528035076 x^48 + 
4813974664 x^49 + 3532331160 x^50 + 2554783500 x^51 + 
1840197183 x^52 + 1306568236 x^53 + 924434043 x^54 + 
644645508 x^55 + 448470745 x^56 + 307216681 x^57 + 210203601 x^58 + 
141532130 x^59 + 95259446 x^60 + 63040614 x^61 + 41765538 x^62 + 
27144679 x^63 + 17701948 x^64 + 11305600 x^65 + 7250417 x^66 + 
4546412 x^67 + 2871683 x^68 + 1763322 x^69 + 1096094 x^70 + 
660630 x^71 + 402853 x^72 + 237206 x^73 + 142759 x^74 + 81694 x^75 + 
48320 x^76 + 26994 x^77 + 15606 x^78 + 8419 x^79 + 4842 x^80 + 
2476 x^81 + 1395 x^82 + 694 x^83 + 374 x^84 + 173 x^85 + 98 x^86 + 
38 x^87 + 22 x^88 + 8 x^89 + 4 x^90 + x^91 + x^92
```

Again, with the caveat that I don't know the specific polynomial expansion so it may well be that your expression for `der` doesn't always converge.